# A matrix to the power of zero gives identity matrix even if it doesn't have an inverse?

Tags: matrices

If one matrix whose determinant is equal to 0 which means it doesn't have an inverse. Then how is possible to find the value of the matrix to the power of 0 equal to identity matrix when multiplying the original matrix with something undefined?

Is it a math fluke, or I am missing some important information?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a good question.

The reason we define $A^0 = I$ is so that the identity 
$$
A^{m+n} = A^mA^n
$$
holds whenever $m$ and $n$ are nonnegative integers. 
Then we can evaluate $p(A)$ for any polynomial $p$, and sometimes even compute with power series to get things like $e^A$.

This all makes sense and is often useful whether or not $A$ is invertible. When it is, we extend the definition so that $A^{-n} = (A^{-1})^n$.

Comment: What if $A$ is the zero matrix?  Are you still defining $A^0$?  For the one dimensional case, this would contradict the usual convention that $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: @Qudit $0^0$ is a special case. Probably best to leave it undefined. But for evaluating $p(A)$ for polynomial $p$ defining it to be $I$ makes everything work.

Comment: It's more than just the zero matrix that this is an issue for. If $A = \mathrm{diag}(1, 0)$, then your definition still implies that $0^0 = 1$.  In fact, the same is true of any matrix that is not invertible if we change the basis.

Comment: @Qudit I don't think we have to debate this further. Any definition (or none) that allows the functional calculus to work is what's required. $e^{\text{diag}(1,0)}$ should come out to $\text{diag}(e,1)$.

Comment: @EthanBolker I was reading Lawrence Perko (Page 13 of Differential Equations and Dynamical System) where he tries to show that the inverse of $e^T$ is $e^{-T}$, if I understand it correctly the corollary 2 uses the fact $e^Te^{-T} = e^0$ is the identity matrix since the summation has $T^0$ in the first term. So I think matrix 0 to the power 0 is also I.